# set the custom Identifier to event kit event

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit

I am using EventKit to store the reminders in the calendar. Here is the code below.
My issue is I want set the custom identifier to the event(do not want to use the one apple assigns).
As the `event.eventIdentifier` is a read-only property I cant not store my custom identifier.

So how to set the custom Identifier?

```
EKEventStore *store = [EKEventStore new];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (!granted) { return; }
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
    event.title = @"My event";
    event.startDate = startDate; //today
    event.endDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];  //set 24 hour meeting
    event.calendar = [store defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
    NSError *err = nil;    
    [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
}];
```